# xmessage over ssh

Tags: command-line, x11, options

The following command prints a message over ssh :
`xmessage Message -display :0 &`
How does it work? there is no -display option in xmessage's man page.

Comment: You mention ssh, is it relevant? If so the display number is probably not your display. You will not normally specify a display number as the DISPLAY  environment variable is used by default.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's included by (obscure) reference.

> **SEE ALSO**
>
> X(7), echo(1), cat(1)

And buried down a ways in `X(7)`:

> **OPTIONS**
>
> Most X programs attempt to use the same names for command line options
>   and arguments.  All applications written with the X Toolkit Intrinsics
>   automatically accept the following options:
>
> `-display display`
>
> This option specifies the name of the X server to use.

followed by a number of other X Toolkit Intrinsics (`Xt`) standard options.  More modern toolkits have similar common options, which you can see with the `--help-all` option.